# SQLAlchemy: Do I need 2 classes for this?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been following the SQLAlchemy Object Relational Tutorial (`http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html`) and I've created `table_def.py`, a file that specifies a table containing Player objects (in my case):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Player(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "players"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstName = Column(String)
    lastName = Column(String)
    college = Column(String)
    ranking = Column(Integer)
    rating = Column(Float)

def __init__(self, rating, college, firstName=None, lastName=None, ranking=None):
    """"""
    self.rating = rating
    self.college = college
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.ranking = ranking
```

This seems to specify everything SQLAlchemy would need to know about player objects.  However, I also have a classes.py file which contains:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,  rating, college, ranking = None, firstName = None, lastName = None):
        self.rating = rating
        self.college = college
        self.ranking = ranking
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

    def to_string(self):
        if self == None:
            return "None Object"
        rep = "firstName is " + self.firstName + " lastName is " + self.lastName + " rating is " + str(self.rating) + " college is " + self.college
        if self.ranking is not None:
            rep = " ranking is " + str(self.ranking) + " " + rep
        return rep
```

I'm actually able to call to_string() on normal Player objects (before I even use the DB).  But it also seems duplicative to have these two definitions of the Player class.

What am I doing wrong / what should I be doing to avoid this?

Thanks,
bclayman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need two classes. You can add the `to_string()` method to the one that's used by SQLAlchemy, and you need to fix the order of the arguments of the `__init__` in the code.

Comment: Hmm, when I comment out the contents of my classes.py file (the Player class described above), I'm no longer able to create a bunch of Player objects in my Python code (before any database functions are called).  How would you recommend getting around this duplication?

Comment: You can create the Player objects but you don't have to add them to session.